# Why do my models look broken?

Tags: materials, fluid-simulation, glass

[image]

This is just a simple liquid tank model.
I'm doing this with a "path" and after convert mesh, bla bla you understand already what im say(just like a doing pipe). I'm adding glass material.
Even if I do it with a path other than "Path", the result is the same, what should I do?

Comment: I don't think it looks broken, this is called _refraction_. If this should be a tank made out of glass, than the glass normally has walls of a certain thickness and it's hollow inside. What you've dreated looks like it's one solid block of glass. So maybe you could add a _Solidify_ modifier to make walls.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/99859/gordon-brinkmann
i add already solidifiy on image
@Gordon-Brinkmann

Answer (score 2):

You have to add some thickness to the walls of the glass tank, otherwise Blender treats it as one solid block of glass - what you call "broken" look is just the strong refraction a very thick glass creates.

The image below shows the difference between a block of glass on the left (i.e., no thickness for the surface polygons) and an empty tank with glass walls on the right (achieved by adding a *Solidify Modifier*).

[image: glass tank]

Comment: i convert the mesh ,i cant add solidify if i add solidifiy modifier 
https://i.hizliresim.com/44qLal.png

Comment: Did you set the shading to "Smooth"? Maybe you then need to enable _Normals_ > _Auto Smooth_ in the _Object Data Properties_.